# How to hide WPF AutoCompleteBox dropdown

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, wpf-controls

I am using MVVM for my WPF application. I have a AutoCompleteBox in my xaml file which works normally. But now, I added a bool flag in my ViewModel `isHideDropDown` which will hide dropdown for the AutoCompleteBox if set to `true`. To summarise, I want my AutoCompleteBox to work as normal TextBox if `isHideDropDown` is set to true.

Can anyone give me some idea?

Thanks

Comment: What AutoCompleteBox are you using? Silverlight one? Then update your tags. In WPF Desktop there is no AutoCompleteBox 'in the Box'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the AutoCompleteBox described [here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/11/autocompletebox-missing-guide/).

Setting the `MinimumPrefixLength` to `-1` will disable the auto complete functionality of the control.

So, if you add an `int MinimumPrefixLength` property to your ViewModel that returns `-1` when `isHideDropDown` is true, then you can bind to that. The other option would be to write a value converter that converts the boolean `isHideDropDown` value to the appropriate integer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. `MinimumPrefixLength` does work. I used converter to control the value.

Answer (score 1):

I have't tried this. But, instead of setting isHideDropDown to true, why not set the object that binds to `ItemSource` property as null?
In an autocompleteBox you need to set the ItemSource. When you don't want the autocomplete feature just set that object to null

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to override ItemContainerStyle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795156%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#customizing_the_appearance_of_the_autocompletebox

Use DataTrigger with Binding to conditionally set ItemContainer's Visibility to Visible/Collapsed